# Where can I find Bootstrap buttons without using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'd like to put some buttons in my web app, with the exact same style like [the ones from bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp).

Does someone have that styles in CSS to be included withtout using bootstrap?

Also, is there a "list" of the styles (templates?) that bootsrap had over time? I remember that in the past the buttons were not flat and now they are...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why won't you use bootstrap though? Bootstrap is open-source, you can always view the stylesheets used for buttons.

Comment: I'd not import a big lib just for buttons. I'm not very practical with CSS and that's why I seek help here :)

Comment: You don't have to import the whole lib, you can customize it - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ Anyways,  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Boodstrap works, you can use styling to make it look like a boodstrap button.